# Solving Non-Linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am trying to find stable/unstable equilibrium points for a physics question.  When I do this, I get the following equation:

$$m \ddot x=-b\dot x-4x(x^2-a^2)$$
Where $\dot x= dx/dt$

I can not figure out the solution to this.  I can do it if I look at only the term that depends on x, but not the term that depends on x^3.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you write them as a pair of first order systems, find the critical points, write the Jacobian matrix and then evaluate the critical points of the Jacobian at those critical points?

Answer (score 1):

Set $\dot{x} = y$ and then set $\ddot{x} = \dot{y}$. From here you will now have a set of two equations that will look like $\dot{x} = y$ and $\dot{y} = \dfrac{-by-4x(x^2-a^2)}{m}.$ From here you find where $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ will be zero simultaneously (equilibrium points). Then you find the Jacobian Matix and evaluate it at each equilibrium point and use the eigenvalues to classify the stability of each point. For more information here is a great source (particularly Chp. 2.):

> *Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations*, 4th ed,
>   Dominic William Jordan, Peter Smith
>   Oxford University Press, 2007
>   [Google Books link](http://books.google.at/books?vid=ISBN9780199208258)

Comment: Also the Jacobian Matrix: $$J = \begin{pmatrix} \partial_x\dot{x} & \partial_y\dot{x} \\ \partial_x\dot{y} & \partial_y\dot{y} \end{pmatrix} $$